# Azure Active Directory Api - Add user To Group Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add user already exists on the azure active directory to a group already exists there too , via Azure AD Graph API:

```
IUser userToBeAdded1 = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(user => user.ObjectId == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx").ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;

            Group retrievedGroup = new Group();
            string searchString = "Development";
            List<IGroup> foundGroups = null;
            foundGroups = activeDirectoryClient.Groups.Where(group => group.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchString)).ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList();

            if (foundGroups != null && foundGroups.Count > 0)
            {
                retrievedGroup = foundGroups.First() as Group;
                if (retrievedGroup.ObjectId != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        activeDirectoryClient.Context.AddLink(retrievedGroup, "members", userToBeAdded1);
                        activeDirectoryClient.Context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nError assigning member to group. {0} {1}",
                            ex.Message, ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "");
                    }
                }
            }
```

and each time i get the same error : 
"The context is not currently tracking the entity."

at this line :

```
activeDirectoryClient.Context.AddLink(retrievedGroup, "members", userToBeAdded1);
```

Comment: Why do you get the user with ExecuteSingleAsync().Result ?

Comment: because I want to add only one user's object . to prove that we can add user to a group programmatically .

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now fixed in the latest version of the Graph client library.  Please see the answer here for details:  [Azure Active Directory Graph Client 2.0 - Context is not currently tracking the entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443449/azure-active-directory-graph-client-2-0-context-is-not-currently-tracking-the)

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

Try this (not tested):

```
var userToBeAdded1 = activeDirectoryClient.Users
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.ObjectId == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");

var searchString = "Development";
var foundGroup = activeDirectoryClient.Groups
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(group => group.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchString));

if (foundGroup != null && foundGroup.ObjectId != null)
{
    try
    {
        activeDirectoryClient.Context.AddLink(retrievedGroup, "members", userToBeAdded1);
        activeDirectoryClient.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nError assigning member to group. {0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "");
    }
}
```

Comment: For activeDirectoryClient.Context.Groups I got : 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper' does not contain a definition for 'Groups' and no extension method 'Groups' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: For activeDirectoryClient.Context.Users I got : 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I edited the code. activeDirectoryClient.Users instead of activeDirectoryClient.Context.Users and activeDirectoryClient.Groups instead of activeDirectoryClient.Context.Groups.

Comment: for activeDirectoryClient.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync is not acceptable by the compiler we can use instead , activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(user => user.ObjectId == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx").FirstOrDefaultAsync () and the same for the groups , any way it gives the same error .