# Azure GraphClient library remove User from Group

Tags: c#, azure

The azure Graph Client library was updated the 22th of december and the method add user to group was fixed.

[Azure Active Directory Graph Client 2.0 - Context is not currently tracking the entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443449/azure-active-directory-graph-client-2-0-context-is-not-currently-tracking-the/27708000#27708000][1])

But is it possible to remove an user from a group?

I tried this method:

```
{groupObject}.Members.Remove({entityObject} as DirectoryObject); 
await myGroup.UpdateAsync();
```

It does not fail but the user is not deleted from the group.

Answer (score 13):

I have found a workaround. Maybe this will help:

```
public void RemoveUserFromGroup(Group group, User user)
    {
            var internalGroup = _activeDirectoryClient.Context.CreateQuery<GraphClient.Internal.Group>("groups/" + group.ObjectId).ToList().First();

            var internalUser = _activeDirectoryClient.Context.CreateQuery<GraphClient.Internal.User>("users/" + user.ObjectId).ToList().First();

            _activeDirectoryClient.Context.DeleteLink(internalGroup, "members", internalUser);
            _activeDirectoryClient.Context.SaveChanges();           
    }
```

Comment: Tried first two ways, one in the library and next the api call provided on the microsoft pages. Both didnt work. Above example worked perfectly, thank you Tomas!

Comment: worked for me in groups that have more than 20 members

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem and was able to diagnose it.  The problem I believe depends on how the group is retrieved -- whether the group's members are included; you can use an **.Expand()** clause for this.

For example, the following *does* work:

```
group = (Group)(await _activeDirectoryClient.Groups.Where(g => g.ObjectId == groupId).Expand(g => g.Members).ExecuteSingleAsync());
user  = (User)(await _activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId == userId).ExecuteSingleAsync());

group.Members.Remove(user);
await group.UpdateAsync();
```

Note, however, that the **.Expand()** operation is limited to 20 objects, so in most cases, the solution from Tomáš is probably safer at the moment.